# How to initiate the call onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)?

Tags: android, upgrade, sqliteopenhelper

I need to upgrade my android sqlite database from version 1 to version 2. But I do not understand how the call `public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)`is initiated? How and when will this method be called? I don't understand where I pass the Version number 2?

[EDIT] I think I need to clarify this question. Here is my class:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context,
            Constants.DB_NAME,
            null,
            1);
}

public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, int version){
    super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, version);
}

public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                               CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
                               CursorFactory factory, int version,
                               DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, factory, version, errorHandler);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // do creation stuff
}
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // do upgrade stuff
}
}
```

So, how does android trigger onUpgrade?

Comment: Simply increase the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant value.

Comment: But where do I do that?

Comment: In your database helper class: `private final static int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;`

Comment: Now you've shared your class we see that you indeed do not have **DATABASE_VERSION** as a variable. Instead you have 3 occurrences of version as a parameter. You can either change all 3 of those every time you upgrade your database version, or pass those thru a constant, just like your **DB_NAME** and only change the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor takes a name and version number, and the helper will invoke the `onCreate` or `onUpgrade` callback as necessary. You need to maintain database version numbers yourself, bumping the version number when a schema change is necessary.

When you need to update your database from version 1 to version 2 just change

`super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, 1);`

to

`super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, 2);`

Then in your `onUpgrade` method you drop tables, add tables, or do anything else needed to upgrade from 1 to 2. `onUpgrade` will only be invoked the first time the SQLiteOpenHelper is instantiated after the version number changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just increment the `DATABASE_VERSION` constant then implement the `onUpgrade` method to correspond to these changes (e.g., creating the table that was newly added in version 2). One thing to understand is that onUpgrade is not used to upgrade the database version, but to update the database after a version upgrade to catch up with the new version.

Take a look at my [source](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4586) for more info.

Comment: Well you should, after all you do need something to keep track of the version to be able to upgrade it. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) on Android SQLite where the "_private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1_; " is correctly used.

Comment: Actually you don't **have to** have a such variable, you can do like Alex Baker explains in his answer and go around using a variable. But I'd say it's better practice to have it as a static variable, pass this variable to the super's constructor.